# JCR node as request bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jcr

I have a MVC application written in Spring. Endpoints are not based on `@RequestMapping`, but on JCR repository. When a request comes, my `HandlerMapping` checks if, for a given path, there's a `Node` in a repository. If it is, then appropriate `Controller` is called. `Controller` fetch data from the repository to setup model, and - if it exists - view name.

So is it correct, to create a JCR `Node` as a request scope bean? In my case `Node` is similar to the model. I don't think, that it is a good idea, to create these nodes as beans since beans should be some service class.

Am I right? If `Node` shouldn't be a bean, what then should I use for the similar solution?

Comment: Nodes basically hold a map of properties and are tied to a JCR session. Therefore, I would create a separate bean and have it populated using the data from the node.

Comment: I was thinking about a similar solution. I created a `RequestedNode` class, that holds some properties, provides some methods (similar to Sling `Resource`), but it's still a model.